# Best method to cluster coordinates around set centroids (Improving Scikit K-Means output? Naive methods?)

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, coordinates, k-means

So basically I have two lists of coordinates, one with "home" points (centroids essentially) and one with "destination" points. I want to cluster these "destination" coordinates to the closest "home" points (as if the "home" points are centroids). Below is an example of what I want:

**Input**:
[home_coords_1, home_coords_2, home_coords_3]
[destination_coords_1, destination_coords_2, destination_coords_3, destination_coords_4, destination_coords_5]

**Output**:
[[home_coords_1, destination_coords_2, destination_coords_5],[home_coords_2, destination_coords_4], [home_coords_3, destination_coords_1, destination_coords_3]]

*given that the "destination" coordinates are in close proximity to the "home" coordinate in its sub-array*

I have already accomplished this with the K-Means clustering function in the scikit python package by passing the home coordinates as the initial centroids. However I noticed that there are some imperfections in the clustering. Also it seems as if this is almost an improper use of K-Means clustering as there is only one iteration happening (see the line of code below).

`km = KMeans(n_clusters=len(home_coords_list), n_init= 1, init= home_coords).fit(destination_coords)`

This brings me to my question: What is the best way to cluster a list of coordinates around a pre-set list of coordinates. An alternative I am thinking about is just running through the list of "home" coordinates and one by one picking *n* closest "destination" coordinates. This seems a lot more naive though. Any thoughts or suggestions? Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: How large is the dataset?  If the number of home points is not too large and the number of destinations is not huge, you could probably just exhaustively calculate the distance from each home point to each destination (using scipy cdist for instance) and take the minimum for each destination.

Comment: I think I can say 99% of all calls to this script will input arrays with lengths of under 100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use e.g. `scipy.spatial.KDTree`.

```
from scipy.spatial import KDTree
import numpy as np

# sample arrays with home and destination coordinates
np.random.seed(0)
home = np.random.rand(10, 2)
destination = np.random.rand(50, 2)

kd_tree = KDTree(home)
labels = kd_tree.query(destination)[1]
print(labels)
```

This will give an array that for each `destination` point gives the index of the closest `home` point:

```
[9 0 8 8 1 2 2 8 1 5 2 4 0 7 2 1 4 7 1 1 7 4 7 4 4 4 5 4 7 7 2 8 1 7 6 2 8
 7 7 4 5 9 2 1 3 3 5 5 5 5]
```

Then for any given `home` point, you can find coordinates of all `destination` points clustered with that point:

```
# destination points clustered with `home[0]`
destination[labels == 0]
```

It gives:

```
array([[0.46147936, 0.78052918],
       [0.66676672, 0.67063787]])
```